# Screen contains MapView and ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

If I create a `MapActivity` that has, in its layout, a `MapView` and a `ListView`. And that I use `findViewById()` to get to the `ListView` will I be able to correctly manage my listview items' onclick events etc?

The fact is that I'm a beginner in Android, and I would like to do 
a layout like this for my tablet :
http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/7623/mapqk.png

First I started to use Fragments, however I encountered some trouble to use MapView inside fragment... So I decided to start from scratch without the Fragment system.

Comment: to be truth if not using fragments you will need to build with tablelayout the leftside using a scrolllayout inside. That's what i would do i don't know if it is that best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work just fine. It is not at all a special layout: you can just use a RelativeLayout and put them side by side, or a set of nested LinearLayouts with appropriate weights. Events should function in standard fashion as well.